# MySQL Query using php explode arrary as WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

After several hours of tinkering I cannot seem to figure this out. I have a table in the database which holds a CSV field full of values. After using the php explode function I am left with an array.

```
$emailarray = list($email) = explode(",", $csv);


while($arrayreadable = mysql_fetch_array($emailarray,$emailcount[0])){



$makefeed = mysql_query("SELECT email,name FROM $statusdatabase WHERE email = $arrayreadable[`0`]'");
while ($friendfeedget = mysql_fetch_assoc($makefeed)) {

[Code for what I want the loop to do]

}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping through and issuing mysql query each time, you can use the `IN` clause in your query like this:

```
$emailarray = list($email) = explode(",", $csv);
$emails = implode(',', $emailarray);

$makefeed = mysql_query("SELECT email,name FROM $statusdatabase WHERE email IN ('".$emails."')");

while ($friendfeedget = mysql_fetch_assoc($makefeed)) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: For some reason I am unable to get your solution to work. The query works without error but the where seems to not find any matches.

Comment: You should specify list of email separated by comma in where clause.